# Error "Unhandled promise rejection" with mysql query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to make a new data entry in BD with mysql from a page. But when throw me an error about promises

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); //Llamadi a MySql
var valida=         require('./modulos/validaciones');

var conection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost', //Host
    user: 'eleazarsb', //Usuario
    password: 'eleazar616', //Contraseña
    database: 'mydb' //Base de datos
}).connect(function(error) {
    if (error) console.log('Problemas de conexion con mysql');
    console.log("conexion Exitosa!");
});

var validaciones = {
    user: false,
    mail: false,
    ced: false
}

//Pendiente: 02
valida.user(data).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.user = rows;
})
valida.mail(data).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.mail = rows;
})
valida.ced(data).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.ced = rows;
    registrar(validaciones);
})


function registrar(validaciones) {
    if (validaciones.user == false && validaciones.mail == false && validaciones.ced == false) {
        var query = conection.query(data.sqlquery(), (error, columna, campos) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log("Entra en registro de BD");
            console.log(columna);
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("No se registro nada");
    };

    return query;
};
```

When 'conection.query(data.sqlquery()...' is execute the console throw me this error 
`(node:1588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
(node:1588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

So, i cant see where is the error if `conection.query(` is declared in the beginning with `conection=mysql.createConnection`

I am new programming with NodeJs so i i accept any comment or suggestion of good programming practices

valida return a promise declared in another file

```js
exports.mail= (data)=>{
 return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{
  var query=conection.query(data.valida_mail(),(error,rows)=>{
   if (error) return reject  (error);
   if(rows[0]){
    console.log("Email Invalido!");
    resolve(true);
   } else {
    console.log("Email Valido");
    resolve(false);
   }
  });
 })
};
```

... for example

Comment: "valida" return a promise declared in another file...

Comment: Please don't use Stack Snippets for code we can't **run** in the browser. Just use code blocks. (Hence my earlier edit.)

Comment: Where does `data` come from? It's not defined prior to use above.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a bit misleading here. The important part is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` which is referring to `conection` being `undefined` when it is called in `registrar` when that is called in the promise handler attached to `valida.ced`.

The issue is with the code:

```
var conection = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
}).connect(function(error) {
  ...
});
```

which is assigning the return value of the call to `Connection.connect` to your `conection` variable. `Connection.connection` does not return a value ([source](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/lib/Connection.js#L79)), so later when that promise resolves and tries to execute `registrar()`, `conection` is still and forever undefined, so there's no such thing as `conection.query` to be called. Try:

```
var conection = mysql.createConnection({
  ...
});

conection.connect(function(error) {
  ...
});
```

As T.J. points out, the *other* important part of the error message is that you should provide code to handle rejected promises. Use the `catch` function to attach these handlers.

Comment: The promise rejection is a symptom, this is what's causing the promise to reject.

Comment: OP is chaining a function to the promise returned by `valida.ced()` that is calling `registrar()` which is attempting to call `query` on a variable that is assigned the return value of a function that does not return a value. It's in the first part of the posted error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`.

Comment: Quite! I suggest folding that into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Will's explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47378686/157247) why your code is failing. The reason you're seeing it as an "Unhandled rejection" error is that you're not handling your promises correctly.

One of the rules of promises is that you either pass on the promise chain to the level above you, or you handle errors. This code does neither (nor do others written largely the same way):

```
valida.user(data).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.user = rows;
})
```

What if the promise returned by `valida.user(data)` rejects? Answer: Nothing handles it.

You must either hand off the promise `then` creates to something else, or handle rejections. (If you hand it off, the thing you had it off to has to hand it off again, or handle errors.)

To make that code handle errors, add a `catch` handler:

```
valida.user(data).then((rows) => {
    validaciones.user = rows;
}).catch(err => {
    // Do something with the error here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answers .

You are using node.js promises . So to handle all type of 'Unhandled promise rejection'. use this code at the main node.js app file

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  // Will print "unhandledRejection err is not defined"
  console.log('unhandledRejection', error);
});
```

In case you missed catching some promise this will handle all of them.

> Process

Node.js `process` is global , it contains unhandledRejection event for handling `unhandled promise rejection` .